# AWS Javascript SDK doesn't connect to cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm doing a very very simple test case of connecting to Cognito using the AWS javascript SDK. I have a user pool set up in Cognito AWS that accepts unauthenticated users. Then I have an HTML page that uses the SDK to connect to it. This part is literally out of AWS's 'sample code' section that is associated with the pool:

```
<script src="aws-sdk.min.js"></script>
<script>
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: "us-east-1:6365757a-3f2c-461d-9b0f-65276555f5c2"
});
```

And then this part is from their docs and should grab temporary credentials:

```
AWS.config.credentials.get(function(){
   var accessKeyId = AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId;
   var secretAccessKey = AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey;
   var sessionToken = AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken;
})
```

When I load the webpage, I get errors for this second part when it tries to retrieve credentials. Safari says "an SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made". Chrome says "net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET".

Have I forgotten some simple and obvious configuration step? Adding the role arn or my accountid to the config step does not help.

Comment: Is this on a desktop computer or in a mobile browser?

Comment: I am testing on a desktop

Comment: Huh. Tried it on mobile just for the heck of it. Worked fine. I thought maybe some kind of network firewall was to blame but confusingly my mobile and my desktop are connected to the same network.

Comment: This could happen if your firewall is intercepting SSL traffic using its own SSL proxy certificate. I cannot explain why it works on your mobile phone but if I had to guess, maybe mobile devices or wireless-connected devices have rules different than those applied to desktop machines or LAN-connected devices.

Comment: Is this a common setup? Should I be worried that people are going to have trouble accessing my app?